# How to make responsive image grid using react-virtualize

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-masonry

I am trying to render the responsive image grid, which might have images of different sizes. It sounds like the Masonry component is good fit for this case, but not sure that I am able to use this [example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Masonry/Masonry.example.js) in my application? It looks fully coupled to the place where it lives, I tried to take relevant parts, but I wasn't able to get working.

Also, I have tried to generate relevant code with [wizard](http://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/wizard), and got this sample:

```
    <AutoSizer>
  {({ height, width }) => (
    <CellMeasurer
      cellRenderer={yourCellRenderer}
      columnCount={numColumns}
      rowCount={numRows}
      width={width}
    >
      {({ getRowHeight }) => (
        <Grid
          cellRenderer={({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) => <div key={key} style={style}>...</div>}
          columnCount={numColumns}
          columnWidth={({ index }) => 100}
          height={height}
          rowCount={numRows}
          rowHeight={getRowHeight}
          width={width}
        />
      )}
    </CellMeasurer>
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

But what should I put instead of `yourCellRenderer`, `getRowHeight`?

Based on some samples in the internet I build following piece of code:

```
<div className="media-viewer" style={{height: "100vh"}}>
        <AutoSizer>
            {({height, width}) => (
                <Grid
                    cellRenderer={({columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style}) => {
                        if (!result[rowIndex][columnIndex]) return <div key={key} style={style}></div>;
                        return (
                            <div key={key} style={style}>
                                <MediaItem key={result[rowIndex][columnIndex].id} app={app}
                                           item={result[rowIndex][columnIndex]}/>
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                    columnCount={5}
                    columnWidth={250}
                    height={height}
                    rowCount={result.length}
                    rowHeight={250}
                    width={width}
                />
            )}
        </AutoSizer>
    </div>
```

And the result it brings to the screen:
[image]

If someone able to provide me with robust example of responsive grid based on `react-virtualize`, or point where I can improve my current code, I would appreciate that.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the image you attached it seems like your images are not dynamically measured. consider adding [this](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/react-virtualized-image-measurer) library

you need to add something like [this](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Masonry.md/#user-content-masonry-example-with-dynamically-measured-images):

```
const MasonryComponent = ({itemsWithSizes}) => {
  function cellRenderer({index, key, parent, style}) {
    const {item, size} = itemsWithSizes[index];
    const height = columnWidth * (size.height / size.width) || defaultHeight;

    return (
      <CellMeasurer cache={cache} index={index} key={key} parent={parent}>
        <div style={style}>
          <img
            src={item.image}
            alt={item.title}
            style={{
              height: height,
              width: columnWidth,
            }}
          />
          <h4>{item.title}</h4>
        </div>
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Masonry
      cellCount={itemsWithSizes.length}
      cellMeasurerCache={cache}
      cellPositioner={cellPositioner}
      cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
      height={600}
      width={800}
    />
  );
};

// Render your grid
render(
  <ImageMeasurer
    items={noCacheList}
    image={item => item.image}
    defaultHeight={defaultHeight}
    defaultWidth={defaultWidth}>
    {({itemsWithSizes}) => <MasonryComponent itemsWithSizes={itemsWithSizes} />}
  </ImageMeasurer>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

if you would like, you can add a fiddle with your code for me (and the community) to take a look.

as for your questions regarding `yourCellRenderer` and `getRowHeight`;

### **cellRenderer**

`yourCellRenderer` should call a function with is responsible for rendering a cell at any given index. it accepts the following parameters:

```
  index, // Index of item within the collection
  isScrolling, // The Grid is currently being scrolled
  key, // Unique key within array of cells
  parent, // Reference to the parent Grid (instance)
  style, // Style object to be applied to cell (to position it);
  // This must be passed through to the rendered cell element.
```

### **getRowHeight**

you can use `cache.rowHeight` to get your specific height

if you would like a more tailored answer, feel free to add a snippet/fiddle with your code.

kind regards